# How come deja-dup doesn't ask me for a password to restore?

Tags: deja-dup

I backed up with deja-dup for the first time, and to restore it doesn't seem to need the password provided. This worries me, because I unselected the option to remember the password. I also want to see if I remember the password correctly, but I can't do that unless it challenges me for it.

How do I make deja-dup forget the password so I can verify that I remember it correctly? This is the first backup, so it will not be a problem if I have to redo it.

Comment: On my 20.04 system the password is stored in the keyring under "backup encryption password".  You could check to see if it's there and delete it if it is.

Comment: How do I see this keyring?

Comment: You don't say what version and/or flavor of Ubuntu you are using, but on my system the keyring app is called `seahorse`, you can type that in a terminal.  In the menus it can be called "Passwords and Keys".

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have that application. Unfortunately, no I don't see the key in there. The only keys are three related to chome, oe for firefox, two for ssh keys, and one for my GNOME Online Account.

Comment: Then there is a good chance that the password was forgotten. You could try having deja-dup remember it and see if it show up in the keyring.

Comment: The thing is, when I select "restore", after some time "Scanning backup files..." it shows the correct files from the backup. When I look at the contents of the disk, they are all .gpg files, described as "GPG symmetrically encrypted data (AES256 cipher)". I don't like the idea that my password for this backup is stored somewhere on the machine, and I'd also like to verify that I remember it correctly, so I'd like to find out where it's kept and delete it.